# How to truncate the begining character from string in mysql for a specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to truncate the first letter of a string which have size more than 11 character.
I know I can use substring function like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 10) from table1;
```

which will truncate and return me the first 10 letter. what should I do if I want to remove the character from the beginning if the string is greater than 10 character.

```
abcdefghijklmn ==>  efghijklmn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `RIGHT()`:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name, 10)
FROM table1;
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/532a9/1/0)

`RIGHT()` returns a specified number of characters from the right side of a string.
If you want to apply any function only in certain situations, a `CASE` statement can be used.

Answer (score 0):

create table table1(name char(25));

insert into table1 values('abcdefghijklmn');
select right(name,10) from table1;

RIGHT() is the function you need to use.